# How to find the next value within a table based on certain criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table:

```
ID | Name | Date
 1 | ABC  | 2015-01-01
 2 | XYZ  | 2015-01-02
 3 | ABC  | 2015-01-03
 4 | ABC  | 2015-01-04
```

I want to query this table such a way that the result becomes:

```
ID | Name | Date       | NextDate
 1 | ABC  | 2015-01-01 | 2015-01-03
 2 | XYZ  | 2015-01-02 | null
 3 | ABC  | 2015-01-03 | 2015-01-04
 4 | ABC  | 2015-01-04 | null
```

One Solution is:

```
select t1.*,
  (select min(t2.Date) from TAB t2 where t2.ID > t1.ID t2.Name = t1.Name) NextDate
from TAB t1
```

But this is very slow as we are doing aggregation on each row. Is there any alternative solution to this which is more efficient than above ?

Comment: Any chance of upgrading your SQL Server 2008 to 2012 or newer? The [`lead`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx) function seems to fit your bill exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `SQL SERVER 2008` does not support `LEAD` window function we have to simulate it using `row_number` and `self join`. Try this

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT t1.*,
                Row_number()
                  OVER(
                    partition BY Name
                    ORDER BY [Date]) AS rn
         FROM   TAB t1)
SELECT a.ID,a.Name,a.Date,b.Date as nextdate
FROM   cte a
       LEFT OUTER JOIN cte b
                    ON a.Name = b.Name
                       AND a.rn + 1 = b.rn ORDER BY a.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to write it would be.

```
Select a.*, c.nextDate  from table a 
outer apply (
        Select top 1 b.Date nextDate from table b 
           where b.Id > a.ID and a.Name = b.Name order by b.id 
) c
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT ID
       ,Name
       ,Date 
       ,(CASE WHEN ID%2 !=0 THEN NextDate ELSE NULL END) AS NextDate
FROM 
(SELECT ID
        ,Name
        ,Date
        ,DATEADD(DAY,1,Date) AS NextDate
FROM YOUR_TABLE) M
```